# Filter inner bag in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

The data looks like this:

```
22678, {(112),(110),(2)}      
656565, {(110), (109)}      
6676, {(2),(112)}
```

This is the data structure:

```
(id:chararray, event_list:{innertuple:(innerfield:chararray)})
```

I want to filter those rows where `event_list` contains `2`. I thought initially to flatten the data and then filter those rows that have 2. Somehow flatten doesn't work on this dataset.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: how did you get this schema. can you add the set of commands you used to get to this schema?

Comment: I'm not really sure on that. This data was stored in a table with this schema.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a simpler way of doing this, like a bag lookup etc. Otherwise with basic pig one way of achieving this is:

```
data = load 'data.txt'  AS (id:chararray, event_list:bag{});

-- flatten bag, in order to transpose each element to a separate row.
flattened = foreach data generate id, flatten(event_list);

-- keep only those rows where the value is 2.
filtered = filter flattened by (int) $1 == 2;

-- keep only distinct ids.
dist = distinct (foreach filtered generate $0 as (id:chararray));

-- join distinct ids to origitnal relation
jnd = join a by id, dist by id;

-- remove extra fields, keep original fields.
result = foreach jnd generate a::id, a::event_list;
dump result;

(22678,{(112),(110),(2)})
(6676,{(2),(112)})
```

Comment: I am not sure why, but when I run only first two lines, the bag is not getting flattened. Here's how the output looks like - (22678, {(112),(110),(2)},)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the Bag and project a boolean which says if 2 is present in the bag or not. Then, filter the rows which says that projection is true or not

So..

```
input = LOAD 'data.txt' AS (id:chararray, event_list:bag{});
input_filt = FOREACH input {
     bag_filter = FILTER event_list BY (val_0 matches '2');
       GENERATE
          id, 
          event_list,
          isEmpty(bag_filter.$0) ? false : true AS is_2_present:boolean;
          ;
};
output = FILTER input_filt BY is_2_present;
```